# wrapped all unwrapped text with <p>

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace

I have this string:

```
$str = 'সাংবাদিক<p>দলীয় সূত্রে</p>'
      .'<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা'
      .'বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">'
      .'বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা'
      .'<p>শাহজাদপুর </p>';
```

and I want to turn into:

```
$str = '<p>সাংবাদিক</p><p>দলীয় সূত্রে</p>'
          .'<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg"><p>বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা</p>'
          .'<p>বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা</p><img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">'
          .'<p>বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা</p><img width="600" src="img/1.jpg"><p>বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা</p>'
          .'<p>শাহজাদপুর </p>';
```

I tried regex

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(?!<p>).*(?!<\/p>)/m', '<p>$0</p>', $str);
```

but not doing properly. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a job for regex but for DOMDocument. Since you are working with html parts and not a whole html document, you need to wrap your string into a basic html skeleton to avoid bad surprises with the auto-correction and to provide the document encoding:

```
$str = 'সাংবাদিক<p>দলীয় সূত্রে</p>'
      .'<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা'
      .'বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">'
      .'বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা<img width="600" src="img/1.jpg">বিলুপ্ত হওয়া পাবনা'
      .'<p>শাহজাদপুর </p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /></head><body>' . $str . '</body></html>');

$bodyNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$result = '';
foreach ($bodyNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= ($childNode->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE)
        ? '<p>' . $dom->saveHTML($childNode) . '</p>'
        : $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```